# In PyCharm, how can I save just the current file?

Tags: save, pycharm

In PyCharm, Cmd-S saves all open files.

I want it to save only the current file on Cmd-S. I want to use Cmd-Shift-S to save all open files. How can I set that up?

Note: I have autosave turned off, like this:

Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > uncheck "Save files on frame deactivation" and "Save files automatically if application is idle"

Comment: If you want to understand how PyCharm file saving works, and differs from everything else, see also http://thehunk.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/disable-auto-save-in-jetbrains-ide.html

Comment: This is the weirdest behavior. Why would they go against a pretty well established default behavior. I can't really think of any good reason to save any files which aren't currently being viewed. This has likely been the source of many of my headaches working with pycharm the past few months.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In PyCharm 4.5.4 there is a command called "Save Document". It saves only the current file.

Go to Preferences > Keymap

Search for "Save All" in the search box on the right. Find the "Save All" command, right-click on it, remove Cmd-S and add Cmd-Shift-S. It may warn you that this will remove Cmd-Shift-S from another command; click "Remove".

Search for "Save Document". Right-click on it and add the Cmd-S shortcut.

On Windows, use Ctrl-S instead of Cmd-S.

Comment: I wish this was the default setup out of the box :(

Answer (score 4):

And to get `SAVE DOCUMENT` to appear in the `FILE` menu, you need to open:

1. `settings->menus`
2. `toolbars->main menu->file`
3. Hit the `+` option to add a command
4. Search for `save document` and select it.

You can move it around in the menu list once it's added.

Comment: Great, thanks! One question. Do you know were the little disk icon is located in Windows? So i can add to this new Save Document shortcut in File (to be like the Save All one).